# Do Indexing works with > or Less than operator?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have one doubt. I have one sql query,

```
select p from Person p where p.succeedOn IS NOT NULL and p.status=? and p.parentId=? and p.personId>?
```

I have created index on personId. My colleague says indexing will not work with > (greater than) OR < (Less than ) but will work with both < and > , as we are defining limit . I searched on google , but not able to find. Kindly help.I am using mysql DB. Thanks

Comment: Indexing may work with less or greater. It depends. But an index won't work with "not equal". This rules are in Oracle but I suppose that something similar should be in MySQL

Comment: What lame DB engine would not support using indexes on `<=`. Never heard that before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use indices for range conditions, but you should create an index so that equality conditions should go first in your case you should create a compound index on succeedOn, status, parentId, personId (in this sequence).

[More on that issue](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/greater-less-between-tuning-sql-access-filter-predicates)